# Looking an android object that will keep time and Date

Tags: android

i can't find any object that i can keep the data and time.
I need to import the time from 'TimePicker' gui object and the date from   'DatePicker' gui object and i can't find any object that can keep it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Calendar class in Android.
Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

You can then use something like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 15);
```

This class will take care of both the date and time of day, and you can manipulate and do calculations with it.

Answer (score 2):

Use Calendar API to convert year, month, day, hour, minutes to timestamp and store the timestamp (long)

Comment: can you please explain ... i'm new on android